# How to Convert/Transform pandas dataframe for analysis using convolutional neural network?

Tags: neural-network, time-series, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

I have time-series dataframes that I want to use in conjunction with a convolutional neural network for pattern/anomaly detection.

Just wondering about how I can transform without losing essential data?

Comment: That depends a lot on "what" are the dataframes. Are they pictures? You can at least rotate them (90°) or add noise. Stretching and rotating by different angles is also an option, if you do that in a way you won't crop any important feature. ---- If you really really need to aument and can't guarantee you won't crop features, maybe you can increase the size of the images and add a black padding around the ones that don't fill the entire frame.

Comment: Thanks for the response daniel, the original dataframes are financial attributes, and this is why I am assessing the best way of transforming the data to be used with convolutional neural network. Do you still think transforming fits?

Comment: Perhaps that can be done, but one must understand how they work. People can probably only help you further if they get to understand your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to form a tensor containing 3D arrays for analysis in Convolutional Neural Networks from a simple Data Frame using a moving window:

```
def windows(data, size):
    start = 0
    while start < len(data):
        #print(start,start+size)
        yield start, start + size
        print(start, start + size)
        start += 1

def segmentor(data,window_size,num_channels):
    segments=np.empty((0,window_size,num_channels)) #create dimensions for height component
    for (start,end) in windows(data,window_size):
        placeholder=data.iloc[int(start):int(end),:] #slices the dataframe to extract that time window
        #Now need to forgo the leftovers in each dataframe:
        if(len(placeholder)==window_size): #If the length of timewindow == specified time-window size,
            pl_=(np.dstack((placeholder.ix[:,i] for i in placeholder))) #stack the columns (depthwise)
            #print(pl_.shape)
            #pl_=pl_.swapaxes(1,2)
            segments=np.vstack([segments,pl_])
            #print(segments.shape)
    return segments
```

The resulting structures can then be passed to generic CNNs.